# react native stream ios screen to local server

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, airplay

I am building a React Native application to be able to stream my phone content to a local NodeJS server.

On android, it works great with `MediaProjectionManager` but on iOS this is more complicated.

I tried to do it with `RPScreenRecorder`, this is my code

```
#import "ScreenShare.h"

@implementation ScreenShare

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

- (NSString *) imageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer
{
  CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
  CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:imageBuffer];
  CIContext *temporaryContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
  CGImageRef videoImage = [temporaryContext
                           createCGImage:ciImage
                           fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                               CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer),
                                               CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer))];

  UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:videoImage];
  NSString *base64String = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
  CGImageRelease(videoImage);

  return (base64String);
}

- (NSArray<NSString *> *)supportedEvents
{
  return @[@"ImageCaptured"];
}

RCT_REMAP_METHOD(start,
                 startWithResolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                 rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
  NSMutableDictionary *result = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  [result setObject:@true forKey:@"success"];
  if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    if([RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder isRecording]) {
      return resolve(result);
    }
    [RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder startCaptureWithHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef  _Nonnull sampleBuffer, RPSampleBufferType bufferType, NSError * _Nullable error) {

      dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if(bufferType == RPSampleBufferTypeVideo) {
          NSString *strEncoded = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
          [self sendEventWithName:@"ImageCaptured" body:@{@"image": strEncoded}];
        }
      });

    } completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
      if(error == NULL) return resolve(result);

      // The user declined application recording
      if([error code] == -5801) {
        return reject(@"401", [error localizedDescription], error);
      }

      reject([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", [error code]], [error localizedDescription], error);
    }];
  } else {
    NSError * error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.xxx.ConnectApp" code:426 userInfo:nil];
    reject([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", [error code]], @"Failed to start screen capture", error);
  };
}

RCT_REMAP_METHOD(stop,
                 stopWithResolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                 rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
  NSMutableDictionary *result = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  [result setObject:@true forKey:@"success"];
  if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    [RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder stopCaptureWithHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
      if(error == NULL) return resolve(result);
      reject([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", [error code]], [error localizedDescription], error);
    }];
  } else {
    NSError * error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.xxx.ConnectApp" code:426 userInfo:nil];
    reject([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", [error code]], @"Failed to stop screen capture", error);
  }
}

@end
```

The video quality is not really good and it stops when I am outside the app. The goal of the app is to be able to stream outside the app and not the app.

I investigate another solution to create an airplay server on my NodeJS local server but I can not found any documentation, the only documentation or module I get are old and did not work.